# A question on left cosets of distinct subgroups and index

Tags: group-theory

Let $H_1 , H_2 , ... , H_k $ be subgroups of $G$ and $x_1,x_2,... ,x_k$ be elements of $G$ such that $G=\cup_{i=1}^k x_iH_i$ , then how do we prove that some subgroup $H_i$ has finite index in $G$ ?

Comment: What role plays $H_1,..., H_k$ in the conditions of $G$? It should not have an $H_k$ instead $H$?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been already treated both [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536479/group-covered-by-finitely-many-cosets) and on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17396/can-a-group-be-a-finite-union-of-left-cosets-of-infinite-index-subgroups). An answer in the latter page points to what I understand to be the first proof of this result as [(4.1) and (4.2) in this paper of B.H. Neumann](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Neumann54.pdf).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, sorry, I will edit the answer, is an *AFAIK*.