# Groups that are finite unions of cosets of cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $G = \bigcup_{a \in A} \langle a \rangle B$ for finite sets $A, B \subset G$. Is $G$ virtually cyclic?

Comment: what is "virtually" cyclic?

Comment: @infinity A group is virtually cyclic if it contains a cyclic subgroup of finite index.

Comment: @Gae.S. thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: Yes. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536479/)

Comment: Thanks, I actually just came up with a proof but I found this surprisingly puzzling.

Comment: My mistake was trying to get a slick algebraic proof for this, dynamically it's more or less obvious, color the group according to the cosets and take a minimal subsystem of the orbit closure.