# If the union of finitely many conjugacy classes is syndetic, are there finitely many conjugacy classes?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated

(Cross-posted to [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377779/if-the-union-of-finitely-many-conjugacy-classes-is-syndetic-are-there-finitely).)

Let $G$ be a finitely-generated group. Write $A^G = \{g^{-1} a g \;|\; a \in A, g \in G\}$, and $A \Subset G \iff A \subset G \wedge |A| < \infty$. Is the following true:
$$ \exists A \Subset G: AA^G = G \implies \exists B \Subset G: B^G = G? $$
In words, if the union of finitely many conjugacy classes is left syndetic, are there finitely many conjugacy classes?

This reminds me a bit of Neumann's trick [Group covered by finitely many cosets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536479/group-covered-by-finitely-many-cosets) but if it can be used I don't see how. I have no other ideas.